# Resize an UIView that contains a TextView

Tags: ios, uiview, textview, customization

Is there a way to insert a TextView inside a customized UIView and then resize the UIView based on the number of lines in the TextView? Something that looks like the message bubbles from the Message app (I believe they are also cells).

Comment: 1. UITextView inherits from UIScrollView which has a [`contentSize`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentSize) property that you might be able to query. 2. You might also want to check out [`sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:)

Answer (score 0):

This is a git project by Alex Barinov that achieves what you are looking to do with a `UITableView`. Using a table view, you are easily able to dynamically add next chat "bubbles" to the bottom of the screen and push the old content up.

http://alexbarinov.github.com/UIBubbleTableView/